# Is there such a thing as an on/off וסת?

Tags: halacha, niddah

Coming off the [recent question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60053/4794) of complex וסתות, what about a pattern of 27,29,30; 28,29,27; 31,29,30?

In this case there is a pattern for every middle one while the rest remain random. Are we קובע a חזקה interspersed with non-מוחזק data?

On the one hand we can equate this to the ox that gores every third person. In that case the people he skips would usually tell us that he doesn't gore, but we look past that and count the pattern. Here too, ignore the random and count the pattern.

On the other hand, in the case of the ox we have a quantified pattern, and here we don't. Any sources or solid arguments are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are examples of such *vessts*.

Shulchan Aruch [Y.D. 189:6](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5498) has the halacha of *vesst yom hachodesh*. The case is that a woman establishes a *vesst* of having her period on Rosh Chodesh for 3 consecutive Roshei Chodashim. Badei Hashulchan #51, citing "poskim," writes that even if she has other periods in between these Roshei Chodashim, she still establishes a *vesst* for Rosh Chodesh.  He writes the same in 189:9 #70 regarding a *vesst* pattern of alternating Rosh Chodesh periods.

This assumption is actually explicit in both the Gemara and the Shulchan Aruch.  [Niddah 39b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=39b&format=pdf) has the case of a woman who has her period on Rosh Chodesh of month one, Rosh Chodesh of month two, day 25 of month two, and then Rosh Chodesh of month three, in which case she still establishes a pattern for Rosh Chodesh, despite the interrupting data of day 25 of month two.  In the Shulchan Aruch, [Y.D. 189:32](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5498) is the case of establishing a *vesst* concurrent with an existing *vesst*, i.e. having established a pattern of Rosh Chodesh, and then establishing an additional pattern for day 20 of the month, despite the Rosh Chodesh pattern continuing.

More than this, there is the case of the [Darkei Moshe 189:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5303) in which he discusses the case of a woman who has periods on Rosh Chodesh Nissan, 2 Iyar, Rosh Chodesh Sivan and 4 Sivan, Rosh Chodesh Tamuz and 5 Tamuz (following a pattern of intervals of 31 days if you discount the interrupting Rosh Chodesh Sivan and Tamuz periods).  Here, the Rema is going so far as to discount the periods which are inconsistant with the intervals to not even consider them as splitting the interval itself!

The Rema [Y.D. 189:13](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5498) applies the same principle in his case of a woman who has periods on Rosh Chodesh Nissan, 20th of Nissan, and Rosh Chodesh Iyar, and he writes that she needs to treat the 9th of Iyar as a day of possible *vesst* due to the *haflaga* of Rosh Chodesh Nissan to the 20th of Nissan *despite the interrupting period on Rosh Chodesh Iyar*.

Note that the Rema is using this principle even for הפלגות, not just for יום החדש.

Comment: So if in her whole life she has her period on Rosh Chodesh three times, that establishes a chazaka? I don't understand how that works.

Comment: @Daniel no, it has to be at consistent intervals. Consecutive, or every other, or every 3rd...

Comment: How long does she have to keep her history?

Comment: @Daniel I restructured some sentences to make that clearer.

Comment: @Daniel I once discussed that with R' Moshe Heinemann. He said that theoretically, _any_ consistent pattern would count, but that one is not required to keep track due to its improbability.

Comment: He said the same about a recurring cycle - i.e. hypothetically a pattern of 28;31;24;26;32;27;31 which then repeated 3 times as 28;31;24;26;32;27;31;28;31;24;26;32;27;31;28;31;24;26;32;27;31 would make a _vesst kavua_ of that base pattern.  But again, one is not required to keep track due to its unlikelihood.

Comment: What would it take to undo that kind of _kavua_, three months or three entire patterns?

Comment: @HaLeiVi It's a good question (+1!).  In a more simple case which follows the same principle (Rabbeinu Chananel's case of 15;16;17;15;16;17;15;16;17), the _Shaarei Tohar_ says you need to undo each day independently, although they do not need to all be undone at once (i.e. each day is looked at as its own pattern). _Lechem V'Simla_ is _mesupak_ about it though.  I assume the same would extend to this case.

Comment: That makes sense, that it is considered three separate וסתות. This is how the Raavad puts it. It is also proof to the Poskim you quoted, that we can ignore the in between months and establish just the ones with a pattern. 

However, this would also mean that it wouldn't apply to הפלגות. You can't have two Haflaga patterns, so you shouldn't be able to have in between patterns either.

Comment: @HaLeiVi see my updates.  Do you have a source that you can't have two _haflaga_ patterns?

Comment: I don't have off hand, but I'll let you know when/if I find. But they are inherently different in this regard because in the monthly pattern having two is having parallel patterns. _Haflagos_ are one dimensional in nature. What you added is about not forgetting the larger _haflaga_ when a new pattern isn't set, and about תחילת מעין which is a separate discussion.

Comment: @HaLeiVi No, the Rema in Darkei Moshe explicitly says that you are _קובע_ the pattern of the הפלגה despite the non-conformative Rosh Chodesh in the middle.

Comment: And even without that, the Rema is calculating the הפלגה despite being interrupted - why would a הפלגה which is not קבוע be _more_ taken into consideration than a קבוע one?

Comment: @HaLeiVi and מעין פתוח over there is on the _original_ Rosh Chodesh period, _not_ the final one - see Rashi there and on 11a.

Comment: I am just saying that bringing in a discussion about what is or isn't an interruption in not the point. By _haflaga_ we have the Gemara's chicken example on 39b. By a month date, since it has to do with the day and not with the interval it is easier to understand how there can be a once-in-three pattern alongside other patterns or non-patterns. Whereas in _haflaga_, which is based off each other, they can't be parallel.

Comment: @HaLeiVi I understand.  I am demonstrating that that is not true.  If it were true, you couldn't have the Rema's _cheshbon_.  If a _haflaga_ is by definition looked at in a vacuum, the Rema's whole discussion falls through.  But if a _haflaga_ is between _some_ two periods, even if they aren't adjacent periods, then the Rema's point makes sense, and then there is no reason why they couldn't be alternating.

Comment: That's true that you can ignore the one in middle. But what we are trying to establish here is not that. The 30 _haflaga_ is not coming off the last 30. It is just reappearing. On the other hand, _rosh chodesh_ and 20 are based on the last _rosh chodesh_ and last 20. Therefore, a once-in-three, by extension is coming off the last similar date three months ago. In other words, there is more than one 'cause' at play. We can't apply this thinking to _haflaga_.